# OpenMP FORTRAN issue with privates

Tags: openmp, fortran90

In the following code, when I am passing the variable "*aa*" as private, the results are getting bad. The code works fine how it is posted, but when I replace the line

```
   !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(iii,iter,y,i,yt) SHARED(bb)
```

with

```
   !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(aa,iter,y,i,yt) SHARED(bb)
```

the code is not working properly.

```
     !!!!!!!! module 
      module common
      use iso_fortran_env
      implicit none
      integer,parameter:: dp=real64
      real(dp):: aa,bb

       contains

      subroutine evolve(y,yevl)
      implicit none
      integer(dp),parameter:: id=2
      real(dp),intent(in):: y(id)
      real(dp),intent(out):: yevl(id)
        yevl(1)=y(2)+1.d0-aa*y(1)**2
        yevl(2)=bb*y(1)
      end subroutine evolve

      end module common

      use common
      implicit none
      integer(dp):: iii,iter,i
      integer(dp),parameter:: id=2
      real(dp),allocatable:: y(:),yt(:)
      integer(dp):: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, IXD

       allocate(y(id)); allocate(yt(id)); y=0.d0; yt=0.d0; bb=0.3d0
       !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(iii,iter,y,i,yt) SHARED(bb)
         IXD=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
       !$OMP DO
        do iii=1,20000; print*,iii  !! EXPECTED THREADS TO BE OF 5000 ITERATIONS EACH
          aa=1.d0+dfloat(iii-1)*0.4d0/2000.d0
            loop1: do iter=1,10 !! THE INITIAL CONDITION LOOP
               call random_number(y)!! RANDOM INITIALIZATION OF THE VARIABLE
                loop2: do i=1,70000  !! ITERATION OF THE SYSTEM
                    call evolve(y,yt)
                    y=yt
                enddo loop2     !! END OF SYSTEM ITERATION
              write(IXD+1,*)aa,yt  !!! WRITING FILE CORRESPONDING TO EACH THREAD
            enddo loop1 !!INITIAL CONDITION ITERATION DONE
         enddo
        !$OMP ENDDO
        !$OMP END PARALLEL
        end
```

What could be the issue? Works fine when I generate "*aa*" from "*iii*" but not when I pass it as a private variable. Thanks in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to carefully analyze your variables, especially to think about which of them would have different values on the different threads at the same time, as those must be declared OMP private. In your case, both variables `aa` and `iii` must be OMP private. Variable `iii` because it is a counter in a loop which is distributed over the threads, and `aa` because it gets a value which depends on `iii`.

EDIT: As each thread calls the `evolve` subroutine itself and `evolve` is supposed to use the thread specific value of `aa` (I guess), you should also pass `aa` to your subroutine instead of using the module variable `aa`.

The routine should look like:

```
subroutine evolve(y, aa, yevl)
  integer(dp),parameter:: id=2
  real(dp),intent(in):: y(id), aa
  real(dp),intent(out):: yevl(id)
    yevl(1)=y(2)+1.d0-aa*y(1)**2
    yevl(2)=bb*y(1)
  end subroutine evolve
```

and the according call in your main program:

```
call evolve(y, aa, yt)
```

Comment: Yes, and I tried doing it also. The result is coming ok only in the case when just *iii* is private. For anyother case *(with private aa, or aa and iii)*, the results are incorrect and all I can see are constant values which is not the case.

Comment: Yes, but your subroutine still uses a shared version of `aa` by host association. I updated the post above accordingly.

Comment: It all worked nicely. Was even able to generalize the code for differential equations following the idea and it performed beautifully. Thankyou so much once again.

Answer (score 4):

`aa` is a module variable. Module variables can either be shared (the default) or `threadprivate`. Example A.32.2f from the OpenMP standard document illustrates that *when module variables are accessed in the dynamic scope of a construct, it is unspecified whether the original variable or the private thread copy is being accessed*. This is not the case with `threadprivate` variables as they are always stored in the thread-local storage, no matter if used inside the lexical scope of a parallel region or not.

There are many scenarios for what happens if you declare a module variable to be private and then access it into a subroutine. What is most likely to happen depends on what kind of analysis the compiler does on the code. Some compilers might detect, that the module subroutine is only called inside the parallel region and hence make `aa` refer to the private copy of each thread. Other compilers might decide to always access the original module variable. On the other hand, if the subroutine gets inlined in the calling subroutine, then it might refer to the same `aa` that is used in the calling context (e.g. the private version if `aa` is declared `private`)

Here is an example of how `gfortran` handles `PRIVATE(iii,aa,iter,y,i,yt)` at the default optimisation level:

```
; aa is declared as a global symbol in the BSS section
    .globl  __common_MOD_aa
    .bss
    .align 8
    .type   __common_MOD_aa, @object
    .size   __common_MOD_aa, 8
__common_MOD_aa:
    .zero   8

; Here is how evolve accesses aa
    ...
    movsd   __common_MOD_aa(%rip), %xmm2
    ...

; Here is how the assignment to aa is done inside the parallel region
    ...
    movsd   %xmm0, -72(%rbp)
    ...
```

The private `aa` is implemented as an automatic variable and stored in the stack of the thread, while `evolve` uses the value of `aa` from the module. Therefore this operator:

```
aa=1.d0+dfloat(iii-1)*0.4d0/2000.d0
```

only alters the value of `aa` inside the thread, while `evolve` uses the original value of `aa` from outside the parallel region.

At the high optimisation level `-O3` `gfortran` inlines `evolve` into the parallel region and...

```
...
mulsd   __common_MOD_aa(%rip), %xmm2
...
```

The inlined code also refers to the global value of `aa` in the module, i.e. the behaviour is consistent between the two optimisation levels.

The same applies to Intel Fortran.

The correct approach is to declare `aa` to be `threadprivate` and to **not** put it in a `private` clause:

```
module common
use iso_fortran_env
implicit none
integer,parameter:: dp=real64
real(dp):: aa,bb
!$OMP THREADPRIVATE(aa)
...
 !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(iii,iter,y,i,yt) SHARED(bb)
   IXD=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
   !$OMP DO
   do iii=1,20000; print*,iii  !! EXPECTED THREADS TO BE OF 5000 ITERATIONS EACH
     aa=1.d0+dfloat(iii-1)*0.4d0/2000.d0
...
```

Now both the parallel region and `evolve` will use a private to each thread copy of `aa`. As access to threadprivate variables is usually slower than access to normal private (stack) variables, on 64-bit x86 systems it might make more sense to pass the value of `aa` as an argument to `evolve` instead as suggested by @Bálint Aradi.

Comment: Thankyou so much for taking time for the insightful and detailed explanation. Made the inner working clearer to me.